# process mysql array with php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array coming from my database I want to format and display with php

```
Array ( 
  [customer] => Array ( 
    [customer_id] => 1 
    [firstname] => Mitchell 
    [lastname] => Bray 
    [order_id] => 3 
    [date_added] => 2012-01-17 11:22:30 
    [name] => iPod Shuffle 
    [quantity] => 1 
  ) 
)
Array ( 
  [customer] => Array ( 
    [customer_id] => 1 
    [firstname] => Mitchell 
    [lastname] => Bray 
    [order_id] => 3 
    [date_added] => 2012-01-17 11:22:30 
    [name] => iPod Touch 
    [quantity] => 1 
  ) 
)  
Array ( 
  [customer] => Array ( 
    [customer_id] => 1 
    [firstname] => Mitchell 
    [lastname] => Bray 
    [order_id] => 14 
    [date_added] => 2012-01-25 08:39:54 
    [name] => iPod Touch 
    [quantity] => 2 
  ) 
) 
Array ( 
  [customer] => Array ( 
    [customer_id] => 1 
    [firstname] => Mitchell 
    [lastname] => Bray 
    [order_id] => 14 
    [date_added] => 2012-01-25 08:39:54 
    [name] => HTC Touch HD 
    [quantity] => 3 
  ) 
) 
Array ( 
  [customer] => Array ( 
    [customer_id] => 2 
    [firstname] => M 
    [lastname] => Bray 
    [order_id] => 15 
    [date_added] => 2012-02-02 14:33:45 
    [name] => HTC Touch HD 
    [quantity] => 1 
  ) 
)
```

I want to display something like:

```
Mitchell Bray
iPod Shuffle qty 3
iPod Touch qty 3
HTC Touch HD qty 3

M Bray
HTC Touch HD qty 1
```

added sql query if that helps

```
$sql =  "
    select c.customer_id, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
           o.order_id, o.date_added, 
           op.name, op.quantity
      from `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c
      inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
      inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op on o.order_id = op.order_id";
```

Comment: I hope this isn't from the one table. If so, your database needs normalising

Comment: Do you have any code you've written on which we could comment? Anything in particular that's not working?

Comment: Borealid i don't know where to start i need to figure out how to loop through and make total product counts i.e. i don't want two records for iPod touch for one customer

Comment: You can find a simple example of connecting to a database, executing a query, and processing the results [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysql.examples-basic.php).

Comment: You need to group by columns.

Comment: what columns do i need to group by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use group by.Modify query like this:

```
$sql =  "select c.customer_id, c.firstname, c.lastname, 
                   o.order_id, o.date_added, 
                   op.name, sum(op.quantity)
            from `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c
            inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
            inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op on o.order_id = op.order_id
group by c.customer_id, op.name
";
```

Check Updated Answer:

```
$sql =  "select c.customer_id, c.firstname, c.lastname, op.name, sum(op.quantity)
                from `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c
                inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op on o.order_id = op.order_id
    group by c.customer_id, op.name
    ";
```

Update 2:

```
$sql =  "select *, sum(quantity)  from (select c.customer_id, c.firstname, c.lastname, op.quantity     from `" . DB_PREFIX . "customer` c
                inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
                inner join `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op on o.order_id = op.order_id
) result
    group by result.customer_id, result.name
    ";
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I'm still getting multiple records for the same products

Comment: now its listing only the first product and quantity for all the products for each customer.

Comment: @Mitchell Bray: You have to remove last inner join. Then it will give your required result. Please check.

Comment: sorry I'm just really confused with this (really out of my depth) not shire how to get rid of last inner join without stuffing the DB_PREFIX part

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7272/discussion-between-somnath-muluk-and-mitchell-bray)

Answer (score 0):

```
$customers = array();

foreach ($data as $key => $values) {

    if (!isset($customers[$values['id']])) {
        $name = $values['firstname'].' '. $values['lastname'];  
        $customers[$values['id']]['name'] = $name;
    } else {
        $customers[$values['id']]['order'][] = $values['name']. ' '. $values['quantity'];
    }
}

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $string = $customer['name'] . '<br/>';
    foreach ($customer['order'] as $oder) {
        $string .= $oder. '<br/>';
    }

    print $string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you are running the insert statement for every product that was selected when a customer places an order, or your database isn't normalized.

My suggestion is to maintain a shopping cart, to which the buyer can add items to then when he confirms the order generate a comma or semicolon separated list of items and store that string in a database column. when you later retrieve it back you will get a string which you can explode to get independent elements.

The better way is to store the itemid's as a concatenated string rather than their names. That was all your order details and your items belonging to that order will be in one row instead of multiple rows for same order.

your database table may look like,

```
  customerid  orderid  items           ordertime
  1           3        23,6,35,41,    2012-01-17 11:22:30
```

after when you explode the items string which contains the id's of the items in that purchase you will get an array of item id's

```
 [23, 6, 35, 41]
```

you can get the item details by using the itemid.

If you also want to store the quantity of the items like (ipod x 3) you can store items string as

```
itemid,quantily;itemid,quantity;itemid,quantity
```